# Propel2 Reverse second run has deleted columns

Tags: propel2

I am new to propel. There doesn't appear to be a version command built in, but composer shows propel2 in my description.

I reverse engineered my scheme and models from the database then took six months off the project, came back, remastered the database directly, deleted the generated-classes, and the generated-reversed-database.

I then ran

```
propel reverse "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=MyVanLog;user=**;password=**"
```

When that completed I opened my schema.xml file and visually verified that the fuel price column no longer exists.

```
<table name="LogEntries" idMethod="native" phpName="Logentries">
<column name="LogEntryId" phpName="Logentryid" type="INTEGER" primaryKey="true" autoIncrement="true" required="true"/>
<column name="UserId" phpName="Userid" type="INTEGER" primaryKey="true" required="true"/>
<column name="RvId" phpName="Rvid" type="INTEGER" primaryKey="true" required="true"/>
<column name="Title" phpName="Title" type="VARCHAR" size="45" required="true"/>
<column name="Description" phpName="Description" type="CLOB"/>
<column name="Longitude" phpName="Longitude" type="DECIMAL" size="10" scale="8"/>
<column name="Latitude" phpName="Latitude" type="DECIMAL" size="10" scale="8"/>
<column name="Temperature" phpName="Temperature" type="DECIMAL" size="3" scale="1"/>
<column name="Private" phpName="Private" type="VARCHAR" size="1" sqlType="bit(1)" required="true"/>
<column name="CreatedOnUTC" phpName="Createdonutc" type="TIMESTAMP" required="true"/>
<column name="ModifiedOnUTC" phpName="Modifiedonutc" type="TIMESTAMP" required="true"/>
<foreign-key foreignTable="Users" name="FK_36">
  <reference local="UserId" foreign="UserId"/>
</foreign-key>
<foreign-key foreignTable="Rvs" name="FK_40">
  <reference local="RvId" foreign="RvId"/>
  <reference local="UserId" foreign="UserId"/>
</foreign-key>
<index name="fkIdx_36">
  <index-column name="UserId"/>
</index>
<index name="fkIdx_40">
  <index-column name="RvId"/>
  <index-column name="UserId"/>
</index>
<vendor type="mysql">
  <parameter name="Engine" value="InnoDB"/>
</vendor>
```

Then I run propel build to generate my models.  I open my base/LogEntries file and it has all the methods to manipulate the field that is no longer there.  I won't paste the entire file, but here is the get method.

```
    /**
 * Get the [fuelpriceinvalid] column value.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getFuelpriceinvalid()
{
    return $this->fuelpriceinvalid;
}
```

Does anyone know what I missed?

Answer (score 0):

I had an extra schema.xml file hanging out in the project directories that was being read instead of the one I generated causing the old fields to generate.  This was likely just a mistake on my part, not a propel bug.